# Blacs: processor grids that do not use all MPI cores

Tags: c++, c, scalapack

I have problems with Scalapack when processor grids do not use all available MPI cores. Say I know the grid to setup `Pc*Pr<=NP`

When I setup a process grid

```
Cblacs_get(0, 0, &ctxt);
const char *order = ( column_major ? "Col" : "Row" );
Cblacs_gridinit(&ctxt, order, procrows, proccols);
Cblacs_gridinfo( ctxt, &procrows, &proccols, &myrow, &mycol );
```

`Cblacs_gridinfo` changes the input grid size from `2`x`2` to `-1`x`-1`. In this case I was testing with `11` MPI cores.

This, by itself, does not raise any errors but when I try to setup a descriptor vector

```
int irsrc = 0, icsrc = 0;
descinit_(descA, &M, &N, &Mb, &Nb,&irsrc,&icsrc,&ctxt, &lda, &info);
```

On processes with ids `4-10` i get error

```
{   -1,   -1}:  On entry to DESCINIT parameter number    6 had an illegal value
```

**QUESTION:**

what is the correct way of handling MPI cores which are not on the grid? Shall I skip everything on all cores for which

```
Cblacs_gridinfo( ctxt, &procrows, &proccols, &myrow, &mycol );
```

returned `myrow=mycol=-1`? Is this a part of API?

Answer (score 0):

Unless someone has a better source, the second post in http://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-forum/viewtopic.php?t=139 provides a C example which calls ScaLAPACK functions only for processes where

```
 if ((myrow>-1)&(mycol>-1)&(myrow<nprow)&(mycol<npcol)) {
    // do the job
    Cblacs_gridexit( 0 );
 }
```